# Can we use Kotlin's higher order function for creation of RecyclerView CustomViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I wanted to create a helper method to make it very easy to set up a new RecyclerView in Android. I achieved this using this helper class:

```
class AirRv {

    companion object {

        fun initAndGetAdapter(
                rv : RecyclerView,
                layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
                viewLayout: Int,
                viewHolder: (view: View) -> RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                bindView: (viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) -> Unit,
                size: () -> Int
        ): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        {
            return initAndGetAdapter(
                    rv,
                    layoutManager,
                    {
                        0
                    },
                    {
                        viewLayout
                    },
                    fun(view: View, viewType: Int) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                        return viewHolder(view)
                    },
                    fun(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, viewType: Int, position: Int) {
                        bindView(viewHolder, position)
                    },
                    { size.invoke() }
            )
        }

        fun initAndGetAdapter(
                rv: RecyclerView,
                layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
                viewType: (position: Int) -> Int,
                viewLayout: (viewType: Int) -> Int,
                viewHolder: (view: View, viewType: Int) -> RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                bindView: (viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, viewType: Int, position: Int) -> Unit,
                size: () -> Int

        ): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        {
            val rvAdapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

                override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
                    return viewType(position)
                }

                override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                    val view = LayoutInflater.from(rv.context).inflate(viewLayout(viewType), parent, false)
                    return viewHolder(view, viewType)
                }

                override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                    bindView(holder, viewType(position), position)
                }

                override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                    return size()
                }

            }

            rv.layoutManager = layoutManager
            rv.adapter = rvAdapter
            return rvAdapter
        }

    }

}
```

Here's my implementation example:

```
val adapter = AirRv.initAndGetAdapter(
                rv,
                LinearLayoutManager(this),
                R.layout.item_layout,
                fun(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                    return RvViewHolder(view)     // NOTICE THIS LINE
                },
                fun(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                    val value = arrayList.get(position).toString()
                    val rvViewHolder = viewHolder as RvViewHolder
                    rvViewHolder.textView.text = value
                },
                { arrayList.size }
        )
```

This works fine. But can I improve this:

`RvViewHolder(view)` (Line no 6)

All the enclosing function does is pass view and retrieve corresponding viewHolder. With Kotlin's higher order function, is it not possible to somehow receive the function definition so that the helper method can create an instance and do the needful to get the corresponding viewHolder internally.

The end user of this helper function (the programmer) shouldn't do this manually. It is very predictable that when the helper library will give him a view, the user will return a viewHolder. Why can't the program do it internally?

If someone could shed some light on this matter, that'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If only there was a way to operate on generic types...

Oh, wait. There is, and it's called generics!

Signatures of your companion functions should look like:

```
fun <T> initAndGetAdapter(
                rv : RecyclerView,
                layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
                viewLayout: Int,
                viewHolder: (view: View) -> T,
                bindView: (viewHolder: T, position: Int) -> Unit,
                size: () -> Int
): RecyclerView.Adapter<T>
```

And

```
fun <T> initAndGetAdapter(
            rv: RecyclerView,
            layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
            viewType: (position: Int) -> Int,
            viewLayout: (viewType: Int) -> Int,
            viewHolder: (view: View, viewType: Int) -> T,
            bindView: (viewHolder: T, viewType: Int, position: Int) -> Unit,
            size: () -> Int

): RecyclerView.Adapter<T>
```

Respectively.

Then you won't need to upcast to `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` all the time.
Also, no need to unsafe `as` casts:

```
val adapter = AirRv.initAndGetAdapter(
        rv,
        LinearLayoutManager(""),
        1,
        fun(view: View) : RvViewHolder {
            return RvViewHolder(view)     // NOTICE THIS LINE
        },
        fun(viewHolder: RvViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val rvViewHolder = viewHolder // No as RvViewHolder anymore
        },
        { arrayList.size }
)
```

Those guys from 2005 sure knew what they were doing.

Remember, I don't have your full code, so you'll have to make some adjustments as you go.

You can read more about generics in Kotlin [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).